# Taking multiple line input from user on java

Tags: java, input

I am trying to get input from user with a for loop but for example if user enters "2" as a "noOfSubPattern" loop does not wait for the second input. I cannot find what is wrong in my code.

```
    int noOfSubPattern;
    String subPattern = "";
    noOfSubPattern = scan.nextInt();        


    for(int i = 0; i < noOfSubPattern; i++)
    {

        subPattern += scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to discard the line terminator after `nextInt()`

```
noOfSubPattern = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); // Discard line terminator

for(int i = 0; i < noOfSubPattern; i++) // ...
```

Comment: You are very welcome. Please accept the answer so that other people in the stackoverflow community can benefit.